# class:before and class:after is not working in ie7

Tags: css

I am using two classes like as  **class:before** and **class:after** for rounded corner purpose in IE7, but its not working in IE7. Could you please help me?

```
.round:before{backgourn:url(top-bg.png) no.repeat top left;}
.round:after{backgournd:url(btm-bg.png) no.repeat bottom left;}`
```

Answer (score 4):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-element selectors are not supported in IE7.

See [this reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for more on browser support.

Comment: They are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://my.opera.com/SublimeYe/blog/2011/07/01/addiing-before-after-and-other-elements-in-ie-with-expression

Setting styles with `.selector .before` and `.selector .after` for IE7

---

```
.round{
zoom:expression(runtimeStyle.zoom = 1, insertAdjacentHTML('', '<div class="before"></div>'), insertAdjacentHTML('', '<div class="after"></div>'));
}

.round .before{backgourn:url(top-bg.png) no-repeat top left;}

.round .after{backgournd:url(btm-bg.png) no-repeat bottom left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

these tags are not working in less than IE9.write a separate style for less than IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Method of displaying text or images before or after the given element's contents using the :before and :after pseudo-elements supports till : **IE8**

For rounded corner purposes you can use the **PIE.htc** for IE versions.
**PIE** supports Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering all kind of the most useful CSS3 decoration features with this **PIE.htc** file.

Here is the dummy **CSS** for your IE Solution.

```
border: 1px solid #696;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #EEFF99;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

for more details about the **PIE** you can the read the article..... http://css3pie.com/

I hope this will help you.